# Firebase database null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a simple number from a firebase database. I have a database that is called "followers" it is structured like so...

```
followers: {
    {userID}: {
        count: 5,
        users: { {userID}: true, ... }
    },
    ...
}
```

Simple right. So, I want to get the "count" object, and avoid a null object reference when that "userID" doesn't exist. So I have a very simple (or at least I thought it was) setup for that...

```
DatabaseReference followersDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("followers").child(user.getUid()).child("count");
followersDB.addListenerForSingleValueEven(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot != null) {
            int followersCount = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            //put value in view;
        } else  {
            //put 0 in view
        }
    }
});
```

One would think that the "if(dataSnapshot != null)" would stop from getting a null value reference, but when I run my app in an emulator I get...

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

Why is it still giving me a null object reference if I am testing for "if(dataSnapshot != null)"? Is there any possible way to check to see if the value is there before assigning it? I thought the if would be enough, but apparently it isn't. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You're never passed `null` for the `DataSnapshot` parameter. To check if a value exists, use `dataSnapshot.exists()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
DatabaseReference followersDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("followers").child(user.getUid());
    followersDB.addListenerForSingleValueEven(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.child("users").exists()) {
                int followersCount = dataSnapshot.child("count").getValue(Integer.class);
                //put value in view;
            } else  {
                //put 0 in view
            }
        }
    });
```

This code implies that if you have any followers, then go and check the number of your followers